# Populating Codeigniter(form-helper)-dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, codeigniter-form-helper

i am have put a loop in java script and within the loop , i create the drop down repeatedly
by calling a div within which my codeigniter form helper dropdown is present, something like this

```
for(){
var demo = $('<select>').attr('name','id_'+i).html($('#demo_id').html()); 
}
```

My demo_id is like this:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<?php echo form_dropdown('sample', $my_var, '', 'id="demo_id"') ?>
</div>
```

Now i want that , for each time the javascript for-loop runs , i want each drop down to select a particular value that i provide, something like

```
var demo = $('<select>').attr('name','id_'+i).attr('value',2).html($('#demo_id').html());
```

but this just sets value of select to 2 , does not populate the drop down with 2 selected

What can i do ?

Note: there is no issue in displaying the dropdown , my javascript is creating the dropdowns perfectly , ie same nos of times the for loop runs , just that i want to know how to populate the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the .val() function, not the attr, like this:

```
var demo = $('<select>').attr('name','id_'+i).html($('#demo_id').html()).val(2);
```

And I think, your version didn't work, because first you create the select element, then you gave a name attribute and a value, but at this point, you don't have any  element inside select.

Comment: hm let me try this , ill get back to you, in a gist

Comment: Which one helped? the .val() or that you moved at the end?

Comment: the code snippet you wrote, ie appending .val(2) to the end after html()... Thank :)